# Find analytically the statistical average $\langle f\rangle$ of function $f(x)$ when sampling x a large number of times.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, average, means

I have a function

$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{3} + 2x \left( \frac{1}{3x} \right)^n$

Where n is a natural number larger or equal than 3 and a constant.
I am sampling the value of x numerically in the interval $x \in [\frac{1}{3}, 1]$ a gazillion times and thus can numerically compute the average $<f>_n$ after a sufficiently large number of evaluations. This way, I can construct the function $f(n) = \langle f\rangle_n$ which is the average value of $f$ for a given $n$ when sampling $x$ sufficiently often. Now, I can compute the average of $f(x)$ numerically, for example, for n = 3 I get $\langle f\rangle_3 = 0.629608$.

However, I should be able to compute this analytically too, which is where I'm failing at. Initially, I tried the approach: 

$\langle f\rangle_n = f_n(\langle x\rangle) = f_n(\frac{2}{3}) = 0.5 \quad$ (for n = 3)

 
Since the average value of x in the above given interval is $\frac{2}{3}$. As you can see, this does not match the numerical result. 
Lastly, I tried the mean value theorem: 
 
$\langle f\rangle_n = \frac{ \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1} f_n(x) \,dx }{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{(n-1)*3^n-9}{(3n-6)*3^n} = 0.5555 \quad $ (for $n = 3$) 
 
which also doesn't match the numerical result. Do you know where I am wrong-headed?

The numerical result has been obtained by evaluating $f_n(x)$ a sufficiently large number of times and simply computing the average value obtained when sampling $x$ in the above given interval.

Comment: The average of a function of $x$ is not necessarily the function applied to the average of $x$. Consider drawing $x$ uniformly from $[-1,1]$, with $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This I also concluded. However, shouldn't the approach with the mean-value-theorem work out? If not, do you know if there is an analytical way?

Comment: That's not the mean value theorem - it's the formula for the mean of the function. It should work, but I don't follow your work. Can you edit your post to show your intermediate steps at evaluating the integral

Comment: I just simulated your function for $n=3$ a million times, and I get the average to be between $0.555$ and $0.556$.

Comment: ahhh no wayy what a stupid mistake. Alright I'll check my code. Thanks man!

Comment: Here's my Python code:  ```x = np.random.uniform(1/3, 1, size=1000000);  y = 1/3 + 2*x/((3*x)**3);  y.mean()```

Answer (score 2):

By [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), if $x$ has density $p$, the mean of a function $f$ is

$$E[f(x)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)p(x)dx,$$

yours being the case where $$f(x)=\frac{1}{3} + 2x \left( \frac{1}{3x} \right)^n\\
p(x)=\frac{1}{1-1/3}\mathbf{1}_{x\in [1/3,1]}$$

assuming you draw $x$ uniformly on $[1/3,1].$

Your computation using the integral is exactly this, and the law of large numbers predicts you should get close to this by simulation. Check your code.